# NDSolve and Runge-Kutta methods

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a coupled system of first-order differential equations using `NDSolve` with the `"FixedStep"` method using fourth order `"ExplicitRungeKutta"`. I've been playing around with the step size and have found that nothing changes above a step size of 10. Does `NDSolve` limit the step size to a maximum of 10? I've tried using `StepDataPlot` to check, and above 10 it doesn't seem to budge. Is there anyway to override this?

Here is the code:

```
g = 10^-6;

m = 10^-7;

f = 10^-6;

φ = 1;

omega[x_, j_] := Sqrt[x.x + m^2 + g/2*φ^2*(Cos[f*j])^2] // FullSimplify;


omegadot[x_, j_] = D[omega[x, j], j] // FullSimplify;


solution = NDSolve[{y1'[j] == omegadot[k[0], j]/(2*omega[k[0], j])*(y2[j] + y3[j]), 
                    y2'[j] == -2*I*omega[k[0], j]*y2[j] + omegadot[k[0], j]/(2*omega[k[0], j])*(2*y1[j] + 1), 
                    y3'[j] == 2*I*omega[k[0], j]*y3[j] + omegadot[k[0], j]/(2*omega[k[0], j])*(2*y1[j] + 1), 
                    y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 0, y3[0] == 0}, 
                   {y1, y2, y3}, {j, 0, 100}, 
                   StartingStepSize -> 20, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}];
```

Comment: It would be helpful to share the equations and the code that you are using.

Comment: You'll want to look at `MaxStepFraction`.

Comment: NDSolve "ExplicitRungeKutta" uses a minimum of points. This value seems to be $11$-points evaluated. So if your interval is smaller than 110, your StepSize is ignored and a smaller value is used.

Comment: @JulienKluge Ah ok, so if I have a bigger interval then it will use the StepSize that I choose then?!

Comment: Yes it does. In your posted code your `StartingStepSize` is 20 so you need an interval bigger than $240$.

Comment: @JulienKluge I see, thanks for the info! By the why, I tried putting in by-hand a fourth order Runge-Kutta method to solve the same system in Mathematica, using a `Do` loop to time-step over the interval with the same step-size and it produced different results (well it agreed for the first half of the interval and then diverged). Are there some subtleties to the Runge-Kutta routine used by `NDSolve`?

Comment: It's not using the classical RK internally. To see the Butcher table of the built-in fourth-order method, run ``NDSolve`EmbeddedExplicitRungeKuttaCoefficients[4, ∞]``.

Comment: @J.M.          How does one interpret the Butcher table? Is `NDSolve` using the coefficients `{119041/8970912, -(595205/
  8970912), 595205/8970912, 1309451/8970912, -(119041/747576)}`? These are 5 coefficients though so how does this correspond to 4th order?

Comment: For guidance: compare the Butcher table for classical RK [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Classic_fourth-order_method) with [how it's specified in *Mathematica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html#205676559). As for the built-in: yes, it has five stages.

Comment: @J.M           Ok, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JulienKluge & OP: Re J.M.'s comment about `MaxStepFraction`: By default it is set to `1/10`, which is why you get at least ten steps no matter what `StartingStepSize` is.  Set it to `MaxStepFraction -> 1` and you can get just one step, if you like. (Forgive me, if you already looked it up. The comments did not reflect that. Yet the docs are full of useful stuff like that.)

Comment: @MichaelE2     Thanks for pointing that out. I was actually trying to get it to do a larger number of steps, so I think in this case it should be ok, right (since I want the step size to be about 50-100)?

Comment: The limit on the ***number*** of steps is determined by `MaxSteps` (default 10,000). On the interval of `{j, 0, 100}` the number of steps of size 50-100, would be 1 or 2. To get a larger number of steps, you're going to have to make the step size smaller. (I feel like there was a typo or some other misunderstanding, since it appears you are talking about increasing both the number of steps and the step size, which obviously can't happen if the interval is fixed.)

Comment: @MichaelE2     Whoops, yes I meant increasing the **step size**, not the number of steps.